# Run-time error "9": Subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

In a module in PERSONAL.XLSB, I called a worksheet (while keeping it open) in a different workbook of the same name. The whole code runs perfectly in the device I wrote it in. However, I had it transferred to a separate device with previously no enabled macros or personal files, and this particular line

```
Set C = Workbooks("Base.xlsm").Worksheets("Base").Range("A1").Offset(0,i)
```

returns (noticed while debugging; it gets highlighted)

```
Run-time error "9":
Subscript out of range.
```

I have no clue how to work around this since it's not happening in my own device. Please help!

**Note.** What the code basically does is copy some elements from the Base Worksheet into 2 sheets of a new workbook. However, in the device with the above problem, all things work perfectly until copying of cells start i.e., creation of the new workbook goes well. However, calling Base results in an error. What really baffles me is that there is no error in my own device. Are there any rules I need to follow to save Base.xlsm (in a separate folder?)

Comment: Is Base.xlsm open, what's the value of the variable 'i' and what data type is 'C'.

Comment: @ACCtionMan Also, the macros are working as desirable in the device I coded them in. I call a macro in base (using a button) and it creates a new workbook and copies some data from Base to the new workbook.

Comment: When you say "C is a workbook type data", do you mean that it has been declared `As Workbook`? If so, what string should be in `.Range("A1").Offset(0,i)`? If the name of the workbook, you should use `Set C = Workbooks(Workbooks("Base.xlsm").Worksheets("Base").Range("A1").Offset(0,i))`. If not, please state what did you want saying about `C` variable.

Comment: @FaneDuru Right sorry. I mistook it for a different variable. I have used  C As Range.

Comment: OK. Now, when stopped on error, moving the cursor over the problematic code line, what does it show  when reaches `Workbooks("Base.xlsm")`, `Workbooks("Base.xlsm").Worksheets("Base")` and `i`? If `i` is not zero, try the next test code lines, just before the problematic one: `Debug.Print Workbooks("Base.xlsm").sheets.count`, then `Workbooks("Base.xlsm").Worksheets("Base").usedRange.address`. Does they return anything in Immediate Window, or an error is raised?